# Jmeter throughput values in CSV File

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

In summary-report, the throughput value is mentioned in sec or min .i.e 21/m,15 sec. but while when I converting to CSV File It is displaying throughput value in decimal  i.e `.28032` or `.338292`. How can I solve this Issue?

Answer (score 0):

When running a JMeter test, throughput is measured in requests per second / minute / hour. The time unit is chosen so that the displayed rate is at least `1.0`, in order to graph the data. When the throughput is saved to a **CSV file**, it is expressed in **requests per second** (or **requests / seconds**).

This means, for example that 30 requests per minute is saved as `0.5` (because `30 / 60 = 0.5`).

So, in the example you posted in your question, calculating `0.28032`:

```
0.28032 = x / 60
0.28032 = y / 3600
x = 16.81
y = 1009.15
```

This means that your load test performed `0.28032` requests per **second**, or `16.81` requests per **minute**, or `1009.15` requests per **hour**.